# Ready/Init event for Kendo Upload?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We use the MVC builders for Kendo upload, but sometimes we need to do something like this:

```
$("#someUploadId").data("kendoUpload").setOptions({
    //some options
});
```

(I realize you can set most things via the wrapper, but there is sometimes custom javascript we need to handle special cases.)

However, if I put this in doc.ready it will fail because it doesn't locate the kendoUpload property.  It's a matter of timing as in doc ready the kendoUploader is still initializing and doesn't exist yet.  I can use a setTimeout to wait for a second and it will work because that gives the kendo control time to initialize, however using setTimeout in this way is obviously a hack and might not be reliable.

Usually libraries like this have some sort of event that signals the control is ready/initialized.  I haven't been able to find any documentation that indicates a similar construct for kendoUpload.  How can I determine when the KendoUpload is ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such event.

However, the JS generated from the MVC builders is simply wrapped in jQuery ready blocks, so what you have to do is put the code that needs to access a widget in a jQuery ready block below the builder directive for said widget.

This will work since all ready blocks are executed sequentially and the widget itself is ready as soon as the plugin method is invoked (there's no async initialization).

You could also try implementing the event yourself, e.g. by creating an initializer object:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var kendoInitializer = {
    widgets: [],
    total: 0,
    waitFor: function (name, number) {
        this.widgets[name] = number;
        this.total += number;
    },
    deferred: deferred,
    promise: deferred.promise(),
    resolveOne: function (name) {
        console.log(name, "initialized", this.total);
        this.removeOne(name);
        if (this.total <= 0) { // could also resolve per widget type etc.
            this.deferred.resolve();
        }
    },
    removeOne: function (name) {
        if (this.widgets.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            this.widgets[name] -= 1;
            this.total -= 1;
        }
    }
};
```

then making each widget register itself with the initializer:

```
kendo.ui.Widget.fn.init = function (originalFn) {
    return function () {
        originalFn.apply(this, arguments);
        // mark one widget as initialized;
        // pass this.options.name and resolve per widget type
        kendoInitializer.resolveOne(this.options.name);
    };

}(kendo.ui.Widget.fn.init);
```

then use it like this:

```
kendoInitializer.waitFor("DropDownList", 1);
kendoInitializer.waitFor("Window", 1);
kendoInitializer.promise.done(function () {
    console.log("all widgets initialized");
});
```

This is just a prototype which requires you to declare the number of widgets you want to wait for; there may be a way around that.

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/3WpqN/1/))

Comment: Thanks, I tested this and it works(for simple case).  Unfortunately in my case there is some strange issue causing the lower doc.ready to not execute sequentially, I suspect because we are deferring the evaluation of `$`

Comment: I see; if this is still a problem, you could try working around that with a solution similar to the one I added to my answer

Comment: My script was included below jquery, so it was not being deferred since jquery was already loaded by then, but the inline builder above jquery was deferred.  What I ended up doing for a workaround is adding a doc.ready script block just after the builder making a function call to the additional setup(above the `@section javascriptIncludes`).  The order would be Kendo MVC builder, `<script>additionalSetup();</script>`, `<script src="...jquery-1.9.1.min.js">`. Ensuring **both** the MVC builder inline and my additionalSetup were deferred(the defer script ensures they are executed in order).

Comment: I didn't realize doc.ready's were deterministic in that they were executed in order, so thanks for that as it helped me work out a solution. In case others come along and are confused by what I mean by deferred evaluation, I am referring to this: http://www.mrclay.org/2010/11/14/using-jquery-before-its-loaded/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-dataBound) event. From the documnetation

> Fired when the widget is bound to data from its data source.

So when the data is bound and drawn to the DOM, this event fires. I'm not sure what you need it for but we're using it to add custom CSS to some of the cells in the row that would be a mess if we used Kendo templates, etc.

Note that this will fire whenever the data is re-drawn to the DOM, i.e. when the table is filtered, sorted, etc.

Comment: Yeh I've used this before, but in this case we needed to set options before the grid pulls its data.  Maybe your answer will be helpful to others with similar situation though.